# How can I append a string to a line when certain conditions are met?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I'm handling large .txt files and we are trying to identify which ones do not comply with the correct amount of characters in a line (80 characters top).

For the sake of this example let's say that we need 10 characters for every line, I need to append "(+Number of extra characters)" and "(-Number of missing characters)" for each line that does not have exactly 10 characters.

Here is what I have so far:

```
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
  if [[ "${#line}" -gt 10 ]]; then
    echo "Mo dan 10 D: ${#line}"
  elif [[ "${#line}" -lt 10 ]]; then
    echo "Less dan 10 D: ${#line}"
  fi

done < "$1"
```

I'm stuck in finding a way to append those two strings I'm echoing in the corresponding line so we can identify them.

I researched about awk and sed but haven't been able to properly loop through the entire .txt file, count the amount of characters in every line and append a string with the appropriate message.

Would appreciate some assistance in either shell scripting or as an awk or sed solution.
Thank You.

Edit: This is an example input file (note white spaces also count as characters)

```
Line 1****
Line 2*****
Line 3*
Line 4****
Line 5****
Line 6**
Line 7****
Line 8********
Line 9****
```

This is the desired output

```
Line 1****
Line 2*****(+1)
Line 3*(-3)
Line 4****
Line 5****
Line 6**(-2)
Line 7****
Line 8********(+4)
Line 9****
```

Comment: If you parse large files I would advise agains any 'if' loops or reading line by line. Can't compile you an answer with awk or sed (don't use sed for that either). I personally prefer using Python as soon as a straightforward regex does not solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For performance reasons, using a *shell loop* to process the lines of a file is the wrong approach** (unless the file is very small).

**A text-processing *utility* such as `awk` is the much better choice**:

```
awk -v targetLen=10 '
  diff = length($0) - targetLen { # input line ($0) does not have the expected length
    $0 = $0 "(" (diff > 0 ? "+" : "") diff ")" # append diff (with +, if positive)
  }
  1  # Print the (possibly modified) line.
' <<'EOF'  # sample input as a here-document
1234567890
123456789
123456789012
EOF
```

This yields:

```
1234567890
123456789(-1)
123456789012(+2)
```

Caveat: The BSD/macOS `awk` implementation is not locale-aware, so its `length` function counts *bytes*, which will only work as intended with ASCII-range characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat lines.in
Line 1****
Line 2*****
Line 3*
Line 4****
Line 5****
Line 6**
Line 7****
Line 8********
Line 9****

$ cat lines.sh
#!/bin/bash
mark=10
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    diff=$(( ${#line} - mark ))
    if [ ${diff} -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "${line}"
    else
        printf "%s (%+d)\n" "${line}" "${diff}"
    fi
done < "$1"

$ ./lines.sh lines.in
Line 1****
Line 2***** (+1)
Line 3* (-3)
Line 4****
Line 5****
Line 6** (-2)
Line 7****
Line 8******** (+4)
Line 9****
```

Answer (score 0):

I based my answer on your original script

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
  nchars=${#line}
  target=10
  if [[ $nchars -gt $target ]]; then
          echo "$line+($((nchars-target)))"
  elif [[ $nchars -lt $target ]]; then
          echo "$line-($((target-nchars)))"
  else
      echo "$line"
  fi

done < "$1"
```

simply use it like this `bash evalscript inputfile > outputfile`